# How to use generic type declarations in java in explained case?

Tags: java, generics, types

I am having hard time understanding the best way to use generic type parameters.

Consider a priority queue implementation that implements an interface and requires all elements to be comparable of  its type. The class has a constructor of with input type collection which provides initial elements. Here are a few alternatives. Can you explain differences? And provide the most general way of such declaration?

```
public class HeapMinPQ<E extends Comparable<E>> implements MinPQ<E> {
     ...
     public HeapMinPQ( Collection<? extends Comparable<E>> source) {
     ...
     }
}


public class HeapMinPQ<E extends Comparable<E>> implements MinPQ<E> {
     ...
     public HeapMinPQ( Collection<? extends E> source) {
     ...
     }
}


public class HeapMinPQ<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements MinPQ<E> {
     ...
     public HeapMinPQ( Collection<? extends Comparable<E>> source) {
     ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I am not offended. It is not a homework. I am studying for an interview. My attempt to implement heap based priority queue.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super & the reason why the most generic type is `E extends Comparable<? super E>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructors should not use `Collection<? extends E>` but `Collection<E>` as the type of the parameter. Also, your examples are incomplete; they don't show how the arguments are intended to be used.

In the first case, `source` contains elements guaranteed to be of type `capture ? of Comparable<E>`. The base type might or might not be compatible with `E`. So it wouldn't necessarily be safe to extract an element from `source` and use it against an `E` instance.

In the second, `source` contains elements guaranteed to be of type `capture ? of E`, which means the base type is compatible with `E`. It would be usable against an instance of `E` as long as the particular subtype doesn't matter.

In the third, the class time is weird. It says that `E` is comparable to its supertypes, which is not generally true for comparable types. It is likely to cause you heartache, and also there's no guarantee that the `capture ? of Comparable<E>` base type of `source` will work to compare to `E` or be otherwise compatible with `E`.

Generally you don't want to mess with captures of `E` in a type generic over `E`, but the full details are complex. I suggest Angelika Langer's excellent site, http://www.angelikalanger.com/, particularly http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html, to obtain more knowledge, as well as the articles on Developerworks and in the Oracle Tutorials.

Comment: One more detail please; does the second case guarantee that all collection elements are comparable with each other? Since I declared E to be that way in class declaration.